# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown not changing display after select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using code right off the Twitter Bootstrap components page.  When I select something from the dropdown box the dropdown still displays the title of the field and not the value selected.

I have the bootstrap.min.js loaded.  It shows up in Chrome Developer Tools.

You can check out my demo on http://fmr.bluebaron.ca

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its supposed to behave like that, maybe you are confusing the behaviour with a dropdown menu in an HTML form?

Try bootstraps drop down **demo's** - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: I literally realized that just after I posted the answer.  Going with http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: cool, if the answer was useful, you can mark check the tick mark so others who come across the question can see the correct solution

Comment: Yeah.  I tried to before but it said that I had to wait 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going your original way. Yes, there might be some features that does not provide the entire functionality out of the box but you can easily implement it with a bit of JQuery. Just add this in your javascript file.

```
$(".dropdown > ul > li > a").on("click", function(){

    var $a = $(this);
    $("#dropdownMenu1").text($a.html());
    $(".dropdown").removeClass("open");

    return false;
});
```

See this demo I made to get your example working - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyo3cp4q/)